# Cross Platform Way to make a directory including subfolders?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

Is there a way using the standard c or c++ library to make a directory, including the subfolders that may be required given a string of the absolute path?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905917/cross-platform-method-of-creating-a-folder-directory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, however if you're willing to use boost:

```
boost::filesystem::path dir("absolute_path");
boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
```

There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3335.html) to add a filesystem library to the standard library that will be based on `boost::filesystem`. Using `boost::filesystem` and appropriate typedefs will put you in a good position to migrate to the future standard when it becomes available for your compiler of choice.

Answer (score 19):

**Yes**, In **C++17**, You can use [`filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

```
#if __cplusplus < 201703L // If the version of C++ is less than 17
#include <experimental/filesystem>
    // It was still in the experimental:: namespace
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#else
#include <filesystem>
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#endif

int main()
{
    // create multiple directories/sub-directories.
    fs::create_directories("SO/1/2/a"); 
    // create only one directory.
    fs::create_directory("SO/1/2/b");
    // remove the directory "SO/1/2/a".
    fs::remove("SO/1/2/a");
    // remove "SO/2" with all its sub-directories.
    fs::remove_all("SO/2");
}
```

**Note** to use only forward slashes `/` and you **may** need to include `<experimental/filesystem>`.

Answer (score 12):

Using the standard library, you'd do it like so in C++:

```
// ASSUMED INCLUDES
// #include <string> // required for std::string
// #include <sys/types.h> // required for stat.h
// #include <sys/stat.h> // no clue why required -- man pages say so

std::string sPath = "/tmp/test";
mode_t nMode = 0733; // UNIX style permissions
int nError = 0;
#if defined(_WIN32)
  nError = _mkdir(sPath.c_str()); // can be used on Windows
#else 
  nError = mkdir(sPath.c_str(),nMode); // can be used on non-Windows
#endif
if (nError != 0) {
  // handle your error here
}
```

Comment: Looks like it does not create subfolders for Windows