# How to create folder if it not exist in c++?

Tags: c++, text-files, directory

I've this simple code:

```
FILE *fIn;
fIn = fopen("c:\\myFiles\\andrea.txt","r");
```

My problem is: if 'myFiles' folder doesn't exist, there is a way to create it directly from my C++ code ? 
And if I have more than one directory in my path, how can I create all of them ?

Comment: If you don't care about your program being not multi platform, you can use `system("any system command from your shell here")`

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows? If so, related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist

Comment: @Borgleader thanks but the file isn't my problem

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm on Unix Ubuntu

Comment: Filesystem operations are operating system-dependent. If you are programming on Windows, use the CreateDirectory call from the Windows API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx. On Linux/Unix, use the mkdir call from the standard C library.

Comment: Before C++17 and [<filesystem>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) there's no platform agnostic way to do that. Luckily, with C++17 you now have [create_directory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory).

Comment: Since C++17, [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory)

Comment: @FBergo thanks for your solution

Comment: Prior to `C++17` there was always [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).  In particular [create_directories](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories).

Comment: @Jarod42 Is it cross platform ?

Comment: std::filesystem is cross-platform, but apparently not supported yet in any production compiler: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support (only supported in the unreleased development version of GCC, not implemented in MSVC or clang yet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Platform Way to make a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358455/cross-platform-way-to-make-a-directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++17 you have the  [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) header which provides [create_directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory). That lets you solve your problem.

If you don't have access to C++17, you have to rely on platform specific APIs.

Comment: Is it cross platform ?

Comment: @A. Ortogni It's part of the standard library, so cross-platform is somewhat implied...

Comment: It is in the [brand new] standard. Whether it is available on your platform depends what toolchains are available on your platform and what standard features they provide. Personally I won't be targetting a platform supporting C++17 for many, many years - you may or may not be in the same boat.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: std::filesystem is cross-platform, but apparently not supported yet in any stable compiler: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support (only supported in the unreleased development version of GCC, not implemented in MSVC or clang yet).

Comment: @FBergo Time will fix that.

Answer (score -1):

In c++, if the file does not exist it will automatically create a new one using the name you entered.
Ofstream file1("myName.txt");
This will automatically create a file named "myName".

Comment: That’s not the question. They’re asking about making directories not text files.

Answer (score -3):

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("c:\myFiles\andrea.txt","r");

Comment: Please expound on what this answer does instead of just posting code.  Also you should be putting 4 spaces in front of your code to format it as code

Answer (score -4):

## include

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("c:\myFiles\andrea.txt","r");

for declaration file