# how can I create a folder(directory) in c++ that works on windwos and linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have to write a program in c++ that creates a directory but it must be work on linux and windows(10) . I already wirte a program that creates a folder(directory) but with the library  it is not compatible with linux .

thank you in advance.

Comment: use library that is compatible with both windows and linux like boost

Comment: If you can use C++17, there is `std::filesystem`.

Comment: See [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50085474/8524922). No need for libraries. The standard cross-platform library does that already.

Answer (score -1):

Use boost library as

```
boost::filesystem::create_directory(path);
```

To use boost, you have to add boost library and use this header for filesystem

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Comment: i cant include that header file

Comment: You have to install boost library first, to include that header.